# Play Framework bindFromRequest() method returns objects with null parameters

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to Play! so I am trying to create a very basic post request that pulls data a user enters into a form. However, when I pull the object from the form, all of its fields are null. For example. Here is a basic class I wrote called user.

```
public class User{

public String email;
public String password;

}
```

Simple. Here is my new user class inside the Controller.

```
    public Result new_user() {
    User user = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest().get();

    System.out.println("Username: " + user.email);
    System.out.println("Password: " + user.password);

    return ok("This worked.");
    }
```

My routes file:

```
GET     /                    controllers.HomeController.start
POST    /accounts/login      controllers.HomeController.new_user()
```

And finally, the HTML form:

```
        <form action = "@routes.HomeController.new_user()" method = "post">
         <input type="text" name="firstname">
         <input type="text" name="lastname">
         <button>Add Person</button>
        </form>
```

I know this does not save to a database, but I really don't see the point in trying if I cant even print out to the console. Essentially what happens is the console will print "null" and "null", regardless of what I enter. I know that it does in fact create the object, as printing user will display something like:

```
models.User@1204f842
```

But the fields are not set! What can I do to get this working?

Edit: I should mention that I checked if the form had any errors, it came back false.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the code in the html:

```
     <input type="text" name="email">
     <input type="text" name="password">
```

Comment: Thank You! I figured it out a few days ago, but this is in fact is the correct fix.